# DrawerLayout.DrawerListener - Detect Gravity Right/Left

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm using a Drawerlayout that can be opened and closed from both sides (left and right) like this:

```
drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

I added a DrawerListener to detect when it's being closed:

```
drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "closed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

        }
    });
```

Is there a way to find out if it was the left or the right drawer that got closed?

Thanks!

Comment: Are u using the same listener for both of drawers ? They are two separated object arent they ?

Comment: No it's one DrawerLayout with two NavigationViews inside. The onDrawerClosed-Method is being called when either of the two Views got closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method `onDrawerClosed` there is a `View` named `drawerView` coming as the argument just check the id of that with your navigationViews ID then you can tell wich one triggered this listener .